# Unix script to count the number of occurrences of a string on lines with another string

Tags: unix, script, grep

I have a file that contains a list of names complete with their year of giving. I'd like to find how often each letter occurs in each name, but I'm kind of at a loss for how to go about this. The file format is:

```
"Given name","Year","Gender"  
"Given name","Year","Gender"
```

Where "Given name" is a string, "Year" is 4-number presentation of the year number and "Gender" is 1 or 2.

Years range from 1917-2017 and there are some 6,5 million unique names, but processing power is not a problem. I have a file splitting the given names to syllables and one where they're treated as whole names. I'd like to run a search that returns instances of each given letter in the Given Name paragraph for each Year value, so that it'd for example be:

```
1029000, a, 1917
5140, b, 1917
67043, c, 1917
```

And repeat for each year. I could do this manually with grep, I think, but it would take forever to run it for each letter and year (due to various foreign letters, there are approximately 50 unique signs total, and I have 100 years worth of data so a total of 5000 runs would be necessary). Could anyone please help me with a simple script that would let me accomplish this without breaking my head with mindless repetition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job with a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my %result;
# open iput file
my $in_file = 'file.txt';   # give the fullpath to the file
open my $fh, '<', $in_file or die "unable to open '$in_file': $!";
# read the file line by line
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    # extract name and year from current line
    my ($name, $year) = $line =~  /"([^"]+)","(\d+)/;
    # Explode the name into letters
    my @letters = split //, $name;
    # increment result for each letter, for current year
    $result{$year}{$_}++ for @letters;
}

dump%result;
```

**Sample input file:**

```
"Given name","2000","Gender"  
"another name","2001","Gender"
```

**Output:**

```
(
  2000,
  { " " => 1, "a" => 1, "e" => 2, "G" => 1, "i" => 1, "m" => 1, "n" => 2, "v" => 1 },
  2001,
  { " " => 1, "a" => 2, "e" => 2, "h" => 1, "m" => 1, "n" => 2, "o" => 1, "r" => 1, "t" => 1 },
)
```

Comment: Cheers! I could use that.

Comment: @JarnoPorkka: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers